# R Plotly Hide legend entries (same trace)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Is it possible to hide some legend categories within the same trace?

For example, in the plot below, I only want to show the first 3 legend entries:

[image: plot image link bc I have no points :(]

```
library(plotly)

USPersonalExpenditure <- data.frame("Categorie"=rownames(USPersonalExpenditure), USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- USPersonalExpenditure[,c('Categorie', 'X1960')]

fig <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Categorie, values = ~X1960, type = 'pie')
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories in 1960',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

fig
```

Comment: Do you want only the first 3 included in your pie? Or do you want everything included but red and purple have no legend?